# .NET 6.0 JavaScript URL image preview

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem with JavaScript script in .NET MVC, I've created 'Create' view with option of adding URL image. This is script I've used, however its not working, thus it was in similar project I did in .NET 5.0

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
  <img id="ProfilePicturePreview" />
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
       $("#ProfilePictureURL").on("change", function () {
           var output = document.getElementById('ProfilePicturePreview');
           output.src = $(this).val();
       })
    </script>
}
```

I've tried renaming the JavaScript method however the problem still exist

Comment: Could you provide more code to reproduce your problem?And what's your problem?

Comment: What's your code about ProfilePictureURL ?

Answer (score 0):

I add ProfilePictureURL like below , hope it can help.

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <img id="ProfilePicturePreview" />
</div>
<input type="text" id="ProfilePictureURL">
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#ProfilePictureURL").on("change", function () {            
            var output = document.getElementById('ProfilePicturePreview');
            output.src = $(this).val();
        })
    </script>
}
```

I text URL :    https://i.stack.imgur.com/baGN2.jpg

result:

[image]